# Symbolic point in an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ in SageMath

Tags: elliptic-curves, sagemath, symbolic-computation

I want to study the behavior of polynomials sitting in the co-ordinates of multiples of a rational point of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}, $ $E(\mathbb{Q}).$
Suppose if we take a point $P = (s,t) \in E(\mathbb{Q}).$ And then we take iteration the point $P$ like $nP , n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then we will have $nP = (f_{n1}/g_{n1}, f_{n2}/g_{n2})$  where $f_{ni}, g_{ni}$ are polynomials in the variables $s,t$.
I want to see those polynomials by using symbolic expression in sage. I tried declaring two symbolic variables $s,t$ but when I assigned the point $P = (s,t)$ error was shown. How to get those polynomials using SageMath?

Comment: I'm sure that even you can do this, your memory will be full after some scalar multiplication. Symbolic computation is not an easy Job. For your question, you may get help from ask.sagemath.org.

Comment: This can be accomplished in *Magma* by base changing the elliptic curve to its own function field:
`E := EllipticCurve([1,1]);
KE<a,b> := FunctionField(E);
EE := ChangeRing(E,KE);
pt := EE![a,b];
for i := 1 to 6 do
i*pt;
end for;`
You can try this code out at the Magma online calculator: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/

Comment: The formulas should be given for a "generic curve" with equation $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ with variables $a,b$, or we have explicit (rational) numbers $a,b$? Then ok, let us say we want those polynomials, what for? (This is important for the implementation.)

Answer (score 1):

If you were intent on making your approach work then in principle one could do the following. Let $E$ be the elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)$ (i.e., specialising $a,b$ you get an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$) given by

$$f(x,y) = y^2 -( x^3 + ax + b) = 0$$

The idea is not to consider $E$ as an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)$, but instead as defining a curve over the function field $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)(E)$ (i.e., an elliptic curve with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)(E)$ with coefficients actually living in $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)$).

In this case $P = (s,t)$ is a generic point on $E$, and we can perform the usual manipulations. In Magma one could do this as

```
K<a,b> := FunctionField(Rationals(), 2);
E := EllipticCurve([a,b]);
F<s,t> := FunctionField(E);
E_F := BaseChange(E, F);
P := E_F![s,t];
```

Note that computations will get expensive fast.

In practice it will be much easier to take the general point summation formulae and repeatedly apply them (if you want to get to large values of $n$, then you'll want to "double and add"). To do this, define some function field $\mathbb{Q}(a,b,s,t, s',t')$ (in Magma you'd do this with `FunctionField(Rationals(), 6)`, not sure what the syntax is in Sage) then define functions giving the numerator and denominators of $(s,t) + (s',t')$ and $2(s,t)$. By iteratively composing these you'll obtain the formulae you want.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: Do we have the equivalent on the SageMath?

Comment: How to achieve this for point $P = (s/u, t/v)$, where $s,t,u,v$ are symbolic variables.